# How to initialise array in react-native using es6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, initialization, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create empty array in react-native using es6. But while accessing it I get an error data not defined.

Here is the code snippet which I am using to initialise the array.

```
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      search: "",
      data: []
    }
  }
```

Here is the code through which I am trying to populate the array and at the same time logging it

```
.then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          data: responseData.hits.hits.map(function(search){
            return{
              name: search._source.service_name
            }
          })
        })
        console.log(data);
```

I think so there is a problem in initialisation of array can anybody rectify it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initializing of the array looks fine.
You just can't access `data` like a local scoped variable. The `data` array in your example is a property/attribute of your state object.

So you need to access your data array like this:
`this.state.data`

Answer (score 1):

Try `console.log(this.state.data)` instead of `console.log(data)`